# How to stick tr in the middle of table when it reaches the top of the page

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

I have a  element with 20  elements in. I would like to have the 15th  stick once it reaches the top of the page similar to how a fixed table header works but for a row in the middle of the table.

I have tried using the 'sticky' property, but as I understand this will only stick an element relevant to its parent so will not work. Is there another way to achieve this? vanilla js is fine but cannot use jquery

Comment: Can you provide code or fiddle link?

Comment: Add some code, even if basic, so people can more easily help. Just what you've already tried.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is to hide each TR one by one as they reach the top of the page (except for your header row of course)

The more obvious route would be to render your header row as a seperate table, but you would have a lot of trouble getting it to match the rest of the table for column width.

Comment: This is a stripped out version of what I have https://jsfiddle.net/9hsep8y5/17

I'd like the "sticky-content" div to remain fixed when it hits the top of the browser